# Which Python Libraries are best to match test strings

Tags: python, list, text, pattern-matching

Which Python Libraries are best to match test strings?

I have a list of suburbs from the city of Auckland, NZ

I also have several million rows of data where the address has a suburb field, but these have all been free form typed in.  This means they have spelling mistakes, and all sorts of weird problems. (Like using MT instead of Mount and other things like that where the data entry operator used a non-standard convention)

I am wanting to use python to find a way to work out which suburb each entry relates to.  But I'm not even sure where to begin.  (I'm still at a fairly basic Python level)

I had thought of possibly assigning numbers to each letter and then trying to build some functions around a kNN match, somebody else has suggested using a Jaccard similarity in some way.

The list of suburbs I want to match to:

```
['ABBOTSFORD', 'ACACIA BAY', 'ADDISON', 'AHUROA', 'AIRPORT OAKS', 'ALBANY', 'ALBANY HEIGHTS', 'ALBANY NORTH', 'ALBANY SOUTH', 'ALBANY WEST', 'ALEXANDRA', 'ALFRISTON', 'ALGIES BAY', 'AOTEA', 'ARARIMU', 'ARCH HILL', 'ARDMORE', 'ARKLES  BAY', 'ARKLES BAY', 'ARMY BAY', 'AUCKLAND CENTRAL', 'AVONDALE', 'AVONDALE NORTH', 'AVONDALE SOUTH', 'AVONDALE WEST', 'AWANUI', 'AWHITU', 'BALMORAL', 'BAYSWATER', 'BAYVIEW', 'BEACH HAVEN', 'BEACH HAVEN NORTH', 'BEACH HAVEN SOUTH', 'BEACHLANDS', 'BELLEVUE', 'BELMONT', 'BETHELLS BEACH', 'BIRKDALE', 'BIRKDALE NORTH', 'BIRKDALE SOUTH', 'BIRKENHEAD', 'BIRKENHEAD POINT', 'BLOCKHOUSE BAY', 'BOMBAY', 'BOTANY', 'BOTANY DOWNS', 'BROOKBY', 'BROWNS BAY', 'BUCKLANDS BEACH', 'BURSWOOD', 'CAMPBELLS BAY', 'CASTOR BAY', 'CHAPEL DOWNS', 'CHATSWOOD', 'CHELTENHAM', 'CLAUDELANDS', 'CLENDON PARK', 'CLEVEDON', 'CLOVER PARK', 'COATESVILLE', 'COCKLE BAY', 'CONIFER GROVE', 'CROWN HILL', 'DAIRY FLAT', 'DANNEMORA', 'DARGAVILLE', 'DEVONPORT', 'DOME FOREST', 'EAST TAMAKI', 'EASTERN BEACH', 'EDEN TERRACE', 'ELLERSLIE', 'EPSOM', 'EPSOM NORTH', 'EPSOM SOUTH', 'FAIRVIEW HEIGHTS', 'FARM COVE', 'FAVONA', 'FLAT BUSH', 'FORREST HILL', 'FREEMANS BAY', 'GLEN EDEN', 'GLEN INNES', 'GLENBROOK', 'GLENDENE', 'GLENDOWIE', 'GLENFIELD', 'GOLFLANDS', 'GOODWOOD HEIGHTS', 'GRAFTON', 'GREAT BARRIER ISLAND', 'GREEN BAY', 'GREENHITHE', 'GREENLANE', 'GREENWOODS CORNER', 'GREY LYNN', 'GULF HARBOUR', 'HALF MOON BAY', 'HATFIELDS BEACH', 'HAURAKI', 'HELENSVILLE', 'HENDERSON', 'HERALD ISLAND', 'HERNE BAY', 'HIGHBURY', 'HIGHLAND PARK', 'HILL PARK', 'HILLCREST', 'HILLSBOROUGH', 'HOBSONVILLE', 'HOKIANGA', 'HOMAI', 'HOWICK', 'HUAPAI', 'HUIA', 'HUNTERS CORNER', 'HUNTINGTON', 'HUNTINGTON PARK', 'HUNTLY', 'HUNUA', 'ISLAND BLOCK', 'JACKS BAY', 'KAEO', 'KAIAUA', 'KAIKOHE', 'KAINGAROA', 'KAIPARA FLATS', 'KAITAIA', 'KAIWAKA', 'KAMO', 'KAMO EAST', 'KAMO WEST', 'KARAKA', 'KARAKA SOUTH', 'KAREKARE', 'KARIKARI', 'KARIKARI PENINSULA', 'KARORI', 'KAUKAPAKAPA', 'KAWAU ISLAND', 'KELSTON', 'KERIKERI', 'KINGSLAND', 'KOHIMARAMA', 'KONINI', 'KUMEU', 'LAINGHOLM', 'LINCOLN', 'LONG BAY', 'LONGFORD PARK', 'LYNFIELD', 'MAHIA PARK', 'MAIRANGI BAY', 'MANGAWHAI', 'MANGERE', 'MANGERE BRIDGE', 'MANGERE EAST', 'MANLY', 'MANUKAU', 'MANUKAU HEIGHTS', 'MANUREWA', 'MANUREWA EAST', 'MARAETAI', 'MARLBOROUGH', 'MASSEY', 'MAUNGATOROTO', 'MAUNU', 'MCLAREN PARK', 'MEADOWBANK', 'MEADOWLANDS', 'MEADOWOOD', 'MELLONS BAY', 'MIDDLEMORE', 'MILFORD', 'MILLWATER', 'MISSION BAY', 'MORNINGSIDE', 'MOUNT ALBERT', 'MOUNT EDEN', 'MOUNT ROSKILL', 'MOUNT WELLINGTON', 'MURRAYS BAY', 'NARROW NECK', 'NEW LYNN', 'NEW PLYMOUTH', 'NEW WINDSOR', 'NEWMARKET', 'NEWTON', 'NGUNGURU', 'NORTH HARBOUR', 'NORTH PARK', 'NORTHCOTE', 'NORTHCOTE CENTRAL', 'NORTHCOTE POINT', 'NORTHCROSS', 'OKURA', 'ONE TREE HILL', 'ONEHUNGA', 'OPAHEKE', 'OPONONI', 'ORAKEI', 'ORANGA', 'ORATIA', 'ORERE POINT', 'OREWA', 'OTAHUHU', 'OTARA', 'OTEHA', 'OWAIRAKA', 'PAHUREHURE', 'PAKURANGA', 'PANMURE', 'PAPAKURA', 'PAPATOETOE', 'PARAKAI', 'PAREMOREMO', 'PARNELL', 'PATUMAHOE', 'PENROSE', 'PIHA', 'PINEHILL', 'POINT CHEVALIER', 'POINT ENGLAND', 'POINT WELLS', 'PONSONBY', 'PORCHESTER PARK', 'PORT ALBERT', 'PUHINUI', 'PUHOI', 'RANDWICK PARK', 'RANUI', 'RED BEACH', 'RED HILL', 'REMUERA', 'RICHMOND PARK', 'RIVERHEAD', 'ROSEDALE', 'ROSEHILL', 'ROTHESAY BAY', 'ROYAL HEIGHTS', 'ROYAL OAK', 'RUATANGATA', 'SAINT HELIERS', 'SAINT JOHNS', 'SAINT MARYS BAY', 'SANDRINGHAM', 'SANDSPIT', 'SCHNAPPER ROCK', 'SHELLY BEACH', 'SHELLY PARK', 'SILKWOOD HEIGHTS', 'SILVERDALE', 'SOMERVILLE', 'STANLEY BAY', 'STANLEY POINT', 'STANMORE BAY', 'STONEFIELDS', 'SUNNYHILLS', 'SUNNYNOOK', 'SUNNYVALE', 'SWANSON', 'TAKANINI', 'TAKAPUNA', 'TAMAKI', 'TARADALE', 'TE ATATU', 'TE ATATU PENINSULA', 'TE ATATU SOUTH', 'THE GARDENS', 'THREE KINGS', 'TIKIPUNGA', 'TINDALLS BAY', 'TITIRANGI', 'TORBAY', 'TOTARA HEIGHTS', 'TOTARA VALE', 'Unkown', 'UNSWORTH HEIGHTS', 'WAIAKE', 'WAIHEKE', 'WAIKOWHAI', 'WAIMAUKU', 'WAIRAU VALLEY', 'WAIUKU', 'WAIWERA', 'WARKWORTH', 'WATERVIEW', 'WATTLE COVE', 'WATTLE DOWNS', 'WELLSFORD', 'WEST HARBOUR', 'WESTERN HEIGHTS', 'WESTERN SPRINGS', 'WESTGATE', 'WESTLAKE', 'WESTMERE', 'WEYMOUTH', 'WHAKATANE', 'WHAKATIWAI', 'WHANGAPARAOA', 'WHANGAREI', 'WHANGAREI HEADS', 'WHAREORA', 'WHENUAPAI', 'WHITFORD', 'WINDSOR PARK', 'WIRI', 'MOUNT MANGANUI, BAY OF PLENTY', 'GLENBERVIE, NEW ZEALAND', 'MATAPOURI, NORTHLAND', 'MAUNGATAPERE, NORTHLAND', 'PAIHIA, NORTHLAND', 'RAWENE, NORTHLAND', 'WAIMAMAKU, NORTHLAND', 'MEREMERE, WAIKATO', 'MORRINSVILLE, WAIKATO', 'TE KAUWHATA, WAIKATO', 'KENSINGTON, WHANGAREI', 'ONE TREE POINT, WHANGAREI', 'ONERAHI, WHANGAREI', 'RAUMANGA, WHANGAREI', 'RAUMAUNGA, WHANGAREI']
```

Here is a small sample of the bad data entry suburbs:

```
['STONFIELDS', 'MT WELLINGTON', 'RD4 ALBANY', 'HAURAKI, NSC', 'GOODWOOD HGTS', 'TE ATATU STH',  'BROWNS BAY NSC', 'AUCKLAND CETNRAL', '    KAMO', 'POINT CHEVALIER SOUTH', 'UNSWORTH HGTS',  'DAIRY FLAT (NORTH SHORE MAIL CENTRE)', 'MANUREWA  (GOODWOOD HGTS)', 'PAKURANG HEIGHTS', 'MANGRE BRIDGE, MANUKAU', 'STANMORE BAY,WHANGAPARAOA', 'SUNNYNOOK, NORTH SHORE', 'SURFDALAE, WAIHEKE  ISLAND', 'ST HELEIRS', 'HENDESON', 'STAAMORE BAY', 'PT CHEVILIER', 'KARAKA PUKEKOHE', 'ALFRISTON  MANUREWA', 'MOUNT ALBERT (SYMONDS ST)', 'STANMOREBAY', 'UNSWORTH HEIGHTS GLENFIELD', 'TE ATATU PENINSULA, WAITAKERE CITY', 'REMUERA         (REMUERA)', 'DANNEMORA EASTTAMAKI HEIGHTS', 'ST JOHNS, REMUERA', 'TAKAPUNA HAURAKI', 'MANUKAU HTS', 'MANUREWA   MANUKAU', 'ORITIA', 'ONE TREE HIL', 'AVONDLAE NORTH', 'OENRAHI', 'SOMMERVALE', 'GLEN EDEN CENTRAL , WAITAKERE', 'MENGERE', 'MOUNT WELLINGTON  (PAKURANGA)', 'WEST HABRBOUR', 'MTROSKILL', 'WATTLKE DOWNS', 'SILVRDALE', 'MT WELLINGTON  CENTRAL', 'POINT CHVEVALIER', 'DAIRY FLAT, RD4 ALBANY', 'PAKIRI, WELLSFORD', 'BEACHLANDS (BOTANY)', 'ROTHESAY BAY, NSC', 'GRAFTON (SYMONDS STREET)', 'OTATHUHU', 'ST MARYS BAY (MATAKANA)', 'OTARA SOUTH  MANUKAU', 'HOMAI, MANUKAU MANUREWA', 'FLATBUSH: MANUKAU', 'ROEHESAY BAY']
```

Any ideas gratefully accepted!
To be clear - I am hoping people will suggest which functions or libraries are the ones I should first try.

Comment: Can you provide some test data?

Comment: I have now provided a sample of both the list of suburbs I want to match to - and more importantly the kind of bad data I am trying to find a fix for.

I am hoping this will be enough detail to have the hold lifted - this is a real world problem I am struggling with and the 1 answer already given is already helpful.  I am hoping others may also be familiar with other libraries and they will post those so that I can try them all...

Answer (score 1):

I have used in the past the `fuzzywuzzy` library of Python for 'fuzzy' matching strings. This means that you can match two strings up to some accuracy (say 95%)

https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy

https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/02/25/fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/

I wouldn't try to re-invent the wheel and write my own matching algorithm. If this is not exactly what you need, there are many other libraries out there doing similar stuff.